# Excel formula that would search multiple text based on another cell in single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search formula that would search multiple text in cell 1 contain in cell 2 but the position is random, please see the result column that I want. For example,

[image: example]

I expected as the result column.

Here the data in [Table Markdown](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) format:

| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Yellow, Black, Red, Green, Purple" | "Black, Red, Green, Orange" | FALSE |
| "Yellos, Black, Red, Green, Purple" | "Black, Red, Green" | FALSE |
| "Yellow, Red, Green, Purple" | "Yellow, Green, Red, Purple" | TRUE |
| "Yellow, Green, Purple" | "Purple, Green, Yellow" | TRUE |

Comment: Quick question though, does this mean that the content of cell1 and cell2 is equal (apart from the placement of the substrings) ***or*** can cell2 contain more substrings despite them not being present in cell1?

Comment: cell2 may contain more substrings despite them not being present in cell1

Answer (score 3):

### Compare Substrings in Two Columns

[image]

**`BYROW (Range)`**

- The strings in the two columns (`fCol`, `sCol`) of each row (`r`) of the range (`data`) are compared using the function (`f`).

```
=LET(data,A2:B5,fCol,1,sCol,2,dl,", ",cl,"""",
    f,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(dl,,SORT(
        TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(x,cl,""),,dl))),"")),
BYROW(data,LAMBDA(r,
    f(INDEX(r,,fCol))=f(INDEX(r,,sCol)))))
```

**`MAP` (Two Columns)**

- The strings in each row of the two columns (`fi`, `se` (`i`, `e`)) are compared using the function (`f`).

```
=LET(fi,A2:A5,se,B2:B5,dl,", ",cl,"""",
    f,LAMBDA(x,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(dl,,SORT(
        TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(x,cl,""),,dl))),"")),
MAP(fi,se,LAMBDA(i,e,f(i)=f(e))))
```

**The Function (`f`)**

- `SUBSTITUTE` is used to remove the double quotes (`cl`) from the string.
- `TEXTSPLIT` is used to return the string split by the delimiter (`dl`) in a column.
- `SORT` is used to sort the column ascending.
- `TEXTJOIN` with the delimiter (`dl`) is used to return the column in a (delimited) string.

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following formula-

```
=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(34),""),,", "),y,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(34),""),,", "),AND(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,y))))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thank youuu, but when 2 cell different value the result is true, for example
cell 1: "Yellow, Black, Red, Green, Purple"
cell 2: "Black, Red, Green"

the result is true, should be false

Comment: Or how to sort based on alphabet so I can use match formula.
example: 
cell 1: "Yellow, Black, Red, Green, Purple" -> "Black, Green, Purple, Red, Yellow"

Comment: Then just switch cell reference inside `LET()` function, try- `=LET(x,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,CHAR(34),""),,", "),y,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(B2,CHAR(34),""),,", "),AND(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(x,y))))
`.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, without `LAMBDA()` helper:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=ISERR(FILTERXML("<t>, "&SUBSTITUTE(B2:B5,"""",)&",<s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A5,"""",),", ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(contains(parent::t/text(),concat(', ',.,',')))]"))
```

Xpath `//s[not(contains(parent::t/text(),concat(', ',.,',')))]` means: Get all s-nodes where it's parent t-node contains the text of the s-node with a leading and trailing comma.

So we are effectively looking to return any s-node that is not a substring of the t-node. Funny enough `FILTERXML()` can return the 1st hit of each calculated input in a dynamic range.

---

If I was to do this through `LAMBDA()` helpers, I'd use:

```
=MAP(A2:A5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,y,AND(ISNUMBER(FIND(", "&TEXTSPLIT(x,{"""",", "},,1)&",",", "&MID(y,2,LEN(y)-2)&",")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an array solution, similar to @P.b's answer, just extended to return the result for all input rows all at once:

```
=LET(f,LAMBDA(x, TEXTSPLIT(MID(x,2,LEN(x)-2),", ")),
 MAP(A2:A5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(a,b, AND(1-ISNA(XMATCH(f(a),f(b)))))))
```

Here the output:
[image: output]

The user `LAMBDA` function `f` encapsulates repetitive task of removing the quotes (`"`) and doing the column split via `TEXTSPLIT`. Since we just need to remove the quotes at the beginning and at the end, we could use `MID` function instead of `SUBSTITUTE`.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but assume, this should also work as per the given markdown data by OP with the expected output:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>K2</kbd>

```
=NOT(ISERR(AND(SEARCH(", "&TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"""",),", ")&", ",", "&SUBSTITUTE(B2,"""",)&", "))))
```

---

Or, using <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=MAP(A2:A5,B2:B5,LAMBDA(x,y,NOT(ISERR(AND(SEARCH(", "&TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(x,"""",),", ")&", ",", "&SUBSTITUTE(y,"""",)&", "))))))
```

---